# UltraWinGrid Infragistics Operations

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have an Ultrawingrid to which I am binding some columns from the database. I group some of the columns with the Ultragrid group so that the result set 
shows up like this:

[image: Grouped Grid]

Now using the ultrawincalc manager the user can add new calculated columns. Can the user choose which ultragroup the columns should be added to? Like can he choose the new column to go under any group?

Also if the Datasource is empty, can I set a "No records" message? If so how?

Thanks,
Dinesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured out as how to do this through our code. so here's what we did.

We allow the users to add a calculated column through a wizard that leverages the ultarcalcmanager engine. We added a dropdown that lists the different ultagroups (Input, Calculated and Final). The user chooses the group in the dropdown and hits save.

The ultragridcolumn can be associated to the ultragridgroup by

```
Grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Groups["DROPDOWNTEXT"].Columns.Add("New Calculated Column");
```

Regards,
Dinesh